# Manipulação de TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms

Simplesmente você preenche os campos `Modelo`, `Placa`, `Km` e isso vai ser salvo nos campos *multiline* abaixo:

[image: Tela com o resultado]

Porém quando clico no botão "Salvar" o resultado é totalmente oposto do esperado. Eu queria que cada campo fosse um a frente do outro e quando chegasse no final `"novoCarro.mostraKm()"` ele pulasse uma linha para então salvar o próximo veículo na próxima linha.

```
txtCarros.Text += novoCarro.mostraModelo() + "/t";

txtCarros.Text += novoCarro.mostraPlaca() + "/t";

txtCarros.Text += novoCarro.mostraKm() + "/r/n";
```

Comment: Não seria \r\n? ou \n

Comment: eu testei com apenas /n e o resultado foi mesmo, mas por via das dúvidas vou editar o tópico

Comment: testasse com a barra invertida? \n?

Comment: outra forma seria txtCarros.Text += Environment.NewLine + novoCarro.mostraModelo()

Comment: Nossa, que vacilo meu, era isso mesmo obrigado :)

Comment: Blz. Vou adicionar como resposta só pra ajudar quem tiver com a mesma dúvida.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A melhor forma de fazer é assim:

```
txtCarros.Text = string.Join("\t", novoCarro.mostraModelo(), novoCarro.mostraPlaca(), novoCarro.mostraKm(), "\n");
```

Ficar concatenando *string* manualmente gera diversas alocações e isto além de ficar lento cria pressão no coletor de lixo. Este caso não faz um grande estrago, mas se aumentar o número de itens vai piorando exponencialmente.

Coloquei as tabulações que é o a pergunta pede, e a quebra de linha somente no final.

De forma simplificada:

```
public class Program { public static void Main() => System.Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\t", "modelo", "placa", "km", "\n")); }
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/WLQEVB). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tGS1ae). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/JoinText.cs).

[Documentação do `Join()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0#System_String_Join_System_String_System_String___).

Mas se está fazendo tudo na mesma expressão é possível simplificar um pouco a sintaxe que o compilador transformará em `Concat()` para você, e aí encaixa até melhor:

```
txtCarros.Text = novoCarro.mostraModelo() + "\t" + novoCarro.mostraPlaca() + "\t" novoCarro.mostraKm() + "\n";
```

Para poucos itens não compensa usar o `StringBuilder`, especialmente quando não se sabe o tamanho final.

Uma outra alternativa seria:

```
txtCarros.Text = $"{novoCarro.mostraModelo()}\t{novoCarro.mostraPlaca()}\t {novoCarro.mostraKm()}\n";
```

Comment: Não sabia desse detalhe, mas muito obrigado vou adicionar os códigos ao meu programa, vlw!

Answer (score 1):

Para quebrar linha do string é só substituir a barra "/t" por barra invertida "\n"

```
txtCarros.Text += novoCarro.mostraModelo() + "\n";

txtCarros.Text += novoCarro.mostraPlaca() + "\n";

txtCarros.Text += novoCarro.mostraKm() + "\n";
```

Outra forma é utilizar String + Environment.NewLine + String.

Answer (score 0):

O que tem de errado o seu código, além da concatenação manual de strings, é estar a usar `/` em vez de `\`, como caractere de escape.
Em vez de `"/t"` deve usar `"\t"` e, para a quebra de linha, `"\n"`.

Para evitar os problemas(lentidão e pressão sobre o colector de lixo) da concatenação manual de strings e que mostra o que você está fazendo use a classe [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
builder.Append(novoCarro.mostraModelo());
builder.Append("\t");
builder.Append(novoCarro.mostraPlaca());
builder.Append("\t");
builder.AppendLine(novoCarro.mostraKm());
txtCarros.Text = builder.ToString();
```